# problems in add a new image attribute in magento 1.9

Tags: attributes

add an image attribute and assign to a new group to an attribute set, but when I create a new product, I can see the group but could not see the table of the new image attribute.

But it will be no problem if create a new text attribute and assign to the attribute set in  the same way.

What is the problem?